# PySpark very slow on Amazon cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working on a Spark project and trying to excecute the app on a cluster on amazon. Performance are very slow also on small file. I don't want a solution, just an opinion about the possible reasons for the experienced slowness.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("appName").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

rec= sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])
#  rec= sc.parallelize(records.collect())

a= rec.map(lambda line: line.split("\t"))
          .filter(lambda x: int(x[6])>=4)
          .map(lambda x: (x[1],[x[2], x[6]]))
a=a.join(a)
   .filter(lambda (x,(a,b)): a[0]<b[0])
   .map(lambda (x,(b,a)): ((a[0],b[0]),x))
   .groupByKey()
   .filter(lambda (x,y): len(set(y))>2)
   .sortBy(lambda a: a[0])
   .saveAsTextFile(sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: what's your definition of *very slow* and *small* ?

Comment: 150 seconds for 300MB.  On Java, with more or less the same operations the duration is 60 seconds

Comment: You should consider reading the file in through Pandas and then pushing it to a Spark RDD

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and/or a schema and number of rows for your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code sequence alone may be causing you the most grief:

```
records = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])
rec= sc.parallelize(records.collect())
```

Why? You're reading the file in as an RDD via the spark context textfile function then it will be materialized across the cluster, then and here's the kicker, by calling records.collect() you're telling the cluster to send ALL the data BACK to the driver (whatever machine launched the job), and finally you'll REBUILD the RDD from that locally collected list. Just use the records RDD in place of the rec RDD

Edit: 
It looks like you're doing a cross join of a to itself. Is that intended and for what purpose?

Group by key forces a shuffle of all the data in contrast to reduce by key.

Stop using the SparkContext; it's there for backwards compatibility. Use your sparksession's `.read.option("delimiter", "\t").csv(file path)` which will create a DataFrame instead of an RDD, parsing the tab delimited lines for you into generic Row objects and critically then by using the DataFrame APIs you can get far better performance (courtesy of Tungsten and Catalyst). This is especially useful since you're using PySpark because by using Spark 2.x with DataFrames and Python, the performance is in line with scala on the JVM whereas using RDDs with Python means the Python interpreters do the work (re Scala is much faster).

Comment: Thanks. anyway i've found that (after removing rec=sc.parallelize) the most time is spent onthe operations:
.sortBy(lambda a: a[0])
.saveAsTextFile(sys.argv[2])
How can I improve the timeof execution?

Comment: Because it's lazily executed the save call will always appear to be the hang up but almost never is.

Comment: Cross join of a to itself it's necessary. I have  the data in the structure of "idPlane, idUser" and I need  the pair of user who take the same plane: idPlane,idUser,idUser. Anyway if i delete the commands    
      .sortBy(lambda a: a[0])
     .saveAsTextFile(sys.argv[2])
the execution time decrease of 80%! I really don't understand how it's possible to avoid this and get the same output. The problem must be linked to these commands!

Comment: @RamsesXVII please provide a small sample input and output. Removing saveAsTextFile means the commands aren't even executed because that's the only action which forces evaluation while the rest are transformers.

Answer (score 0):

Well PySpark or Spark in general is made for use cases where you need to deal with a lot of data. It is expected that it is slow for small data. Here are the reasons:

1. In PySpark depending on how many executors you have it needs to spin up JVM first. Moreover, in case of PySpark an additional overhead is created through the Python sub-processes which needs to be invoked as well.
   [image: PySpark Internals]
2. The second reason is due to data shuffling. Your data might be shuffled around the network. In a local case the data is calculated on the same node. For distribution of data the scheduler needs to figure out first where it needs to put the data and then also what to do with it.

So PySpark/Spark only shines when you need to do something with "big data"! I've seen many people get very disappointed at first because they say that Spark is slow but they only used it for very small data amount. Hope this helps!